# Typical mid-scale business computer system of the late 70s

Tags: dec, ibm, minicomputers

What was the most common business computer system of the late 70s, just before the Apple II and CP/M really started proliferating?

For concreteness, let's say we are talking about a U.S. company on the order of 100 employees, in the business of something other than computers or electronics, having a need to process orders, payroll and so forth. What would they most often have? IBM? DEC? What sort of mix of in-house operations and contracting? Was there a lot of diversity, or was there a fairly standard setup?

Comment: Wang and HP9100, I'd say.

Comment: I don't know about USA but in Poland, they'd outsource that to a firm with an IBM mainframe providing this kind of services. In my town, anything smaller than two giants (a chemical factory of ~5k employees, and a heavy industry factory with ~3k employees) who wanted to "computerize" their firm or organization would use services of ZETO, a computational center, a firm specializing in that sort of work. There were no computers that would have sufficient capabilities for a justifiable price for anything smaller than 1000 employees, but the cost shared between many customers made it possible.

Comment: @SF. And that's in 1970's Poland? I'd be interested in learning more about that. How did the computer service connect to their customers? Dial-up or something else?

Comment: @Wilson I would *guess* that you physically carried the data to the computing firm for processing, much like how we nowadays upload data over the Internet to computing firms for processing.

Comment: My Dad's company at the time (paper wholesaler, 5 - 10 employees) bought a minicomputer, stuck it in an off-site room with a bank of modems and connected via Decwriter http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/la36.html - which was my start on a 40 year journey into computers. To share the cost they had a few other small companies renting time on the system.

Comment: France and Germany wouldn't have used PDP-11 outside science and education. France had their Bull minicomputers and Germany Nixdorf and Siemens, Italy would mainly have used Olivetti computers, Great Britain had ICL.

Comment: If you were in certain vertical industries it would have been a BASIC/4.  (Or Wang, probably.)  If you had one.  But you probably didn't have an IT department or anything like that to write software.  You bought the whole system, hardware and software for your industry, from the ISP/service provider.  Industries were: dental offices, car dealerships (sales and parts), warehouse operations, like that.  Each had an ISP (or more than one) that supported them with software.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Israel, in the early 1980s (I started work as an accountant in 1982 so I don't know how long the system had been in use prior to this date), all the kibbutzim of an area used to connect to one PDP-11 which was run from a communal computing centre. Each kibbutz had one data line. We had programs for accounting and a precursor of what was to be ERP, as well as more esoteric programs, such as one for maintaining a database of avocado trees.

All we had originally was a DEC-Writer: we used to use the paper four ways. Eventually we bought a VT-100 terminal.